# How can i call crystal report viewer when Click linkbutton within DataGridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, crystal-reports

I created an orders webform with datagridview , I created also one report by using crystal report .I put also crystalreportviewer down datagridview same page.

This is the list of gridview columns for webform and datagridview :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewHome" runat="server"  AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewHome_PageIndexChanging">

           <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>Patient MRN#</HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblpatient" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Patient No") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>Order Number</HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblorder" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Request number") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>Patient Name</HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Patient Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>Req. Date</HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblreqd" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Request Date") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>Report Date</HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblrepd" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Report Date") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>Test Name</HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="LblTest" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Test_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>Result</HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="result" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Result") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>Ref.Range From</HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Reflow" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Low Range") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>To</HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="refhigh" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("High Range") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>Text Range</HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="textrange" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Text Range") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>REQ. FORM NO.</HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="req" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("REQ FORM NUMBER") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>Dept.Id</HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="deptid" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DEPT ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>Department</HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="deptname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Department") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>Options</HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="Lnkresult"  runat="server" OnClick="Lnkresult_Click">Print Result</asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
```

this is gridview picture :
[image]

I expect when press the link button (Print Result) show the report down datagridview depending on OrderNum and deptid parameters.

I created the linkbutton and i used the following code :

```
protected void Lnkresult_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow iRow = ((GridViewRow)((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer);

            //Assuming you first column is where your "lblOrder" is.
           int OrderNum = Convert.ToInt32(((Label)iRow.Cells[1].Controls[1]).Text);
           int Deptid = Convert.ToInt32(((Label)iRow.Cells[11].Controls[1]).Text);

            ReportDocument myReportDocument;
            myReportDocument = new ReportDocument();
            myReportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/RPT/RPT_RESULTS.rpt"));
            myReportDocument.SetParameterValue("@ORDER_ID", OrderNum);
            myReportDocument.SetParameterValue("@deptid", Deptid);
            myReportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon("username", "password");
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myReportDocument;
            CrystalReportViewer1.DisplayToolbar = true;
        }
```

but when i click link button it not show the report what is the error with my code ?

Comment: If I get it correct, you are writing code for Report in the click event of this button? What is the issue? You want to view Report as well in that Web form or grid?

Comment: The issue simply i need when press on (Print Result) in gridview open the crystal report viewer and the report on the other form . the report ready i built it just i need to open it .

Comment: Well, place the Report Viewer control in webform and call the code in Button event. Follow this link - https://www.tektutorialshub.com/crystal-reports/how-to-create-crystal-reports-in-asp-net-webforms/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add hyperlink in your datagridview and call your webform and send parameters to your crystal report viewer by using this code :

```
<asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>Options</HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1"  NavigateUrl='<%#"/RPT/WebForm1.aspx?order_id=" +Eval("Request number")+"&DEPT ID=" +Eval("DEPT ID")+"&Test Id=" +Eval("Test Id")%>' runat="server">Print Result</asp:HyperLink>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

and in page load of webform create number of textbox 2 or 3 or 4 textbox depends on your parameters then in page load use this code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

              TXTORDERID.Text = Request.QueryString["order_id"].ToString();
                TXTDEPTID.Text = Request.QueryString["DEPT ID"].ToString();
                TXTTESTID.Text = Request.QueryString["Test Id"].ToString();
                ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
                ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();
                ParameterField paramField = new ParameterField();
                ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();



                        paramField.Name = "@ORDER_ID";
                        paramDiscreteValue.Value = TXTORDERID.Text.ToString();
                        paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
                        paramFields.Add(paramField);

                        paramField = new ParameterField(); 
                        paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();  
                        paramField.Name = "@deptid";
                        paramDiscreteValue.Value = TXTDEPTID.Text.ToString();
                        paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
                        paramFields.Add(paramField);

                        CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;
                        CrystalReportViewer1.ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh = true;
                        CrystalReportViewer1.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Web.ToolPanelViewType.None;
                        reportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/RPT/RPT_RESULT.rpt"));
                        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;
                        reportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon("DBA", "2006");
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Thank you its working great and easy way to use hyperlink and query string :)